# Importing pre-trained embeddings into Tensorflow's Embedding Feature Column

Tags: tensorflow, gensim, word2vec, transfer-learning

I have a TF Estimator that uses Feature Columns at its input layer. One of these is and `EmbeddingColumn` which I have been initializing randomly (the default behaviour).

Now I would like to pre-train my embeddings in gensim and transfer the learned embeddings into my TF model. The `embedding_column` accepts an initializer argument which expects a callable that can be [created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237419/feature-column-pre-trained-embedding) using `tf.contrib.framework.load_embedding_initializer`.

However, that function expects a saved TF checkpoint, which I don't have, because I trained my embeddings in gensim.

The question is: how do I save gensim word vectors (which are numpy arrays) as a tensor in the TF checkpoint format so that I can use that to initialize my embedding column?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! This worked in Tensorflow 1.14.0.

You first need to turn the embedding vectors into a `tf.Variable`. Then use `tf.train.Saver` to save it in a checkpoint.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


ckpt_name = 'gensim_embeddings'
vocab_file = 'vocab.txt'
tensor_name = 'embeddings_tensor'
vocab = ['A', 'B', 'C']
embedding_vectors = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
], dtype=np.float32)

embeddings = tf.Variable(initial_value=embedding_vectors)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver({tensor_name: embeddings})
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    saver.save(sess, ckpt_name)

# writing vocab file
with open(vocab_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(vocab))
```

To use this checkpoint to initialize an embedding feature column:

```
cat = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file(
    key='cat', vocabulary_file=vocab_file)

embedding_initializer = tf.contrib.framework.load_embedding_initializer(
    ckpt_path=ckpt_name,
    embedding_tensor_name='embeddings_tensor',
    new_vocab_size=3,
    embedding_dim=3,
    old_vocab_file=vocab_file,
    new_vocab_file=vocab_file
)

emb = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(cat, dimension=3, initializer=embedding_initializer, trainable=False)
```

And we can test to make sure it has been initialized properly:

```
def test_embedding(feature_column, sample):
    feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_column)
    print(feature_layer(sample).numpy())

tf.enable_eager_execution()

sample = {'cat': tf.constant(['B', 'A'], dtype=tf.string)}

test_embedding(item_emb, sample)
```

The output, as expected, is:

```
[[4. 5. 6.]
 [1. 2. 3.]]
```

Which are the embeddings for 'B' and 'A' respectively.